# Assign the same rank if multiple users have same count value

Tags: mysql

i have user_points Table with  two columns.

select user_values, userid from user_points, based on count of userid i want to assgin the rank to users.. i have write this query

```
SELECT count_temp.* ,  @curRank:=(@curRank + 1) AS rank
 FROM (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS totalcount FROM user_points t GROUP BY t.userid
 ) AS count_temp 
, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r 
ORDER BY totalcount DESC;
```

gives the result as :

---

userid   | totalcount  | rank

---

```
2        6      1
3        2      2
4        2      3
1        1      4
```

but i want to assgin to rank 2 for userid 3 and 4 because their totalcount are same ..

Comment: So userid=1 should have rank of 3 or 4?

Comment: no, userid=1 should have rank=4, further users should have their own rank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To emulate `RANK()` function, which returns the rank of **each row** within the partition of a result set, you can do

```
SELECT userid, totalcount, rank
  FROM
(
  SELECT userid, totalcount, 
         @n := @n + 1, @r := IF(@c = totalcount, @r, @n) rank, @c := totalcount 
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
      FROM user_points t 
     GROUP BY t.userid
     ORDER BY totalcount DESC
  ) t CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT @r := 0, @n := 0, @c := NULL
  ) i
) q;
```

Output:

```
| USERID | TOTALCOUNT | RANK |
|--------|------------|------|
|      2 |          6 |    1 |
|      3 |          2 |    2 |
|      4 |          2 |    2 |
|      1 |          1 |    4 |
```

To emulate `DENSE_RANK()` function, which returns the rank of rows within the partition of a result set, **without any gaps in the ranking**, you can do

```
SELECT userid, totalcount, rank
  FROM
(

  SELECT userid, totalcount, 
         @r := IF(@c = totalcount, @r, @r + 1) rank, @c := totalcount
    FROM 
  (
    SELECT userid, COUNT(*) AS totalcount 
      FROM user_points t 
     GROUP BY t.userid
     ORDER BY totalcount DESC
  ) t CROSS JOIN 
  (
    SELECT @r := 0, @c := NULL
  ) i
) q;
```

Output:

```
| USERID | TOTALCOUNT | RANK |
|--------|------------|------|
|      2 |          6 |    1 |
|      3 |          2 |    2 |
|      4 |          2 |    2 |
|      1 |          1 |    3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e932/1)** demo for both queries